# Normalize glTranslatef()

Tags: c, opengl

The arguments to glTranslate() specify the amount of units by which the origin is translated. Hence, there is a possibility of moving beyond the display. Is there a way to normalize the amount we move so that we don't go beyond the drawing area?

Comment: What do you mean by "normalize"?  Do you just mean clamping the values?  Are you working in 2D or 3D?

Comment: Let's say 2D. Could the argument be normalized.. say x = 1.0 would take us from center to the left boundary.. just so that we dont go beyond the drawing area. Thanks!

Comment: How do these units correspond to actual display area. For example, how much should I translate from the center along x for instance to reach the edge of the drawing area?

Answer (score 6):

> The arguments to glTranslate() specify the amount of units by which the origin is translated.

No (yet another reason people should stop learning fixed-function GL).

`glTranslate` generates a *matrix*, which is right-multiplied by the current matrix to become the new current matrix. It does create a translation matrix, but it's not necessarily moving from the center of the *screen*. For example, this is perfectly valid:

```
glTranslatef(10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f);
glTranslatef(0.0f, 50.0f, 0.0f);
```

It's also valid to do this:

```
glTranslatef(10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f);
glRotatef(90.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glTranslatef(0.0f, 50.0f, 0.0f);
```

This does a translation, then a 90-degree rotation about the Z axis. This affects the final translation performed.

You could also throw a scale in there.

If you want to keep an object on-screen, it's up to *you*, not OpenGL.

Comment: Thanks. How do these units correspond to actual display area. For example, how much should I translate from the center along x for instance to reach the edge of the drawing area?

Comment: With the default projection matrix, your drawing area is the range [-1, 1] on all three axes. You can always create a projection matrix to change those bounds.